# storing into arrays from text file in c

Tags: arrays, sorting, text, integer, scanf

First off, I'd like to introduce myself to you all, as I am new to the forum; my name is Max, and I'm a beginner in C. **I am having trouble creating a program that can do the following:**

1. Create a single array for the cars data.
2. Create three parallel arrays for the chicken data, skipping lines in the input file when reading.
3. Create a character and integer array for the pollution data, and finally
4. Allow the user to select how to display the data (ascending or descending).

**The data can be found below:**
https://github.com/untamedspud/Lab-Assignment-8-data-files/blob/master/motorway.txt
https://github.com/untamedspud/Lab-Assignment-8-data-files/blob/master/pollution.txt

I really appreciate any help you guys can give me, let me know if you have any questions.

**Here is my current non-functioning code for the function that will read the data from the text files and store the data into the appropriate array:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/home/TU/tue44432/include/selectionSort.h"


// Using a C global constant variable.
// The only global variables you can use in your program are const.
const char *filename = "pollution.txt";

int main()
{
    FILE *F;                // C file structure
    int i = 0;
    int level[30];
    int pl;                 // holds the first value we read in from the file
    char city[30];          // holds the second value we read in from the file

    // associate the internal file name, F, with the external file name, pop.txt.
    F = fopen( filename, "r" );

    fscanf( F, "%d ", &pl );
    fgets( city, 30, F );
    chomp( city );                     // removes the newline at the end of the line         read in
    level[0] = pl;

    while ( ! feof( F ) ) {
//          printf("Pollution level is %d in %s.\n", pl, city);
            printf("Pollution level is %d in %s.\n", level[i], city);
            fscanf( F, "%d", &pl );    // scan in the first value from the file
            fgets( city, 30, F );      // reads in UP TO 30 characters, stopping at the
            chomp( city );
            i += 1;
            level[i] = pl;


//              printf("loop controll variable i == %d.\n", i);



}

    fclose( F );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It would help to know what the data in the file looks like. An snippet from pollution.txt for example. Otherwise, all that can be offered is generic answers to your problem.